# Difference between Tubular and Tall Tubular Inverter Batteries

Tags: batteries, inverter, battery-chemistry

What is a difference between Tubular and Tall Tubular Inverter Batteries with same configuartions?

Why are Tall Tubular batteries are priced high than Tubular Batteries?

Tall battery have warranty of 3 years and tubular of 2 and half years.

For example, I have 2 option for an inverter battery, but cant judge which to add with the inverter.

Manufacturer - **Luminous**

Tall Tubular Specs - https://www.luminousindia.com/products-62/power-backup-solutions/batteries/ec-18036.html

Tubular Specs - https://www.luminousindia.com/products-62/power-backup-solutions/batteries/pc-18042tj.html

Can anyone can explain?

Thanks

Comment: Link? Ask the manufacturer?

Comment: Well, the dealer is saying there is not much difference in both kind of batteries.

Comment: Again, links to the datasheets? Ask the manufacturer?

Comment: "Tall battery have warranty of 3 years and tubular of 2 and half years" could mean that the "tall" version is made to last longer or undergoes more thorough testing.

Comment: @winny Links added. I just asked the dealer about it..

Comment: hi @AndrewMorton, thanks for the reply, yeah, you are right but in what specs a tall battery is better than short tubular battery.

Answer (score 2):

I am using both short tubular and tall tubular batteries. The difference I found that the tall tubular batteries' life is longer than the short tubular. On an average a short tubular battery lasts for 6-8 years while a tall tubular battery lasts for 8-10 years. The backup time and charging time is quite the same.